# I need to add text on image mapping selected area,

Tags: javascript, imagemap

I have created the image mapping code through https://www.image-map.net/. But i want to show the seat number as a text on the selected coorrdinate, so that user can understand and click on the given coordinates. Hope i am able to clear the question. Please provide the solution, Thanks in advance.

[Here is the url](https://codepen.io/uibeast/pen/QWjxLKd)

```
 <img src="https://www.roomsketcher.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/RoomSketcher-Office-Floor-Plan-with-Garden-3D-PID3861359.jpg" usemap="#image-map">    
<map name="image-map">
    <area target="_self" alt="seat 1" title="seat 1" href="" coords="49,52,10" shape="circle">
    <area target="_self" alt="seat 2" title="seat 2" href="" coords="95,52,9" shape="circle">
    <area target="_self" alt="seat 3" title="seat 3" href="" coords="69,90,12" shape="circle">
    <area target="_self" alt="seat 4" title="seat 4" href="" coords="161,52,10" shape="circle">
    <area target="_self" alt="seat 5" title="seat 5" href="" coords="203,51,9" shape="circle">
    <area target="_self" alt="seat 6" title="seat 6" href="" coords="179,78,13" shape="circle">
    <area target="_self" alt="seat 7" title="seat 7" href="" coords="251,35,13" shape="circle">
    <area target="_self" alt="seat 8" title="seat 8" href="" coords="301,70,9" shape="circle">
    <area target="_self" alt="seat 9" title="seat 9" href="" coords="282,93,10" shape="circle">
    </map>



.seat1 {
            position: relative;
        }

        .seat1:before {
            position: absolute;
            content: 'seat 1';
            background: red;
            color: #fff;
            width: 45px;
            padding: 2px 5px;
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        img {
            position: relative;
            filter: grayscale(100%);
        }
```

Comment: Please provide what you've tried.

Comment: Any other way or idea is also welcome

Comment: i was try to add seat 1 in red background on the given codepen url

Comment: Add the relevant code to the question itself.

Comment: i have added  all the code. meanwhile i have created the codepen for the reference: https://codepen.io/uibeast/pen/QWjxLKd

Comment: Where is the JS?

Comment: i haven't added any js.This site https://www.image-map.net/ provides the html code with coords

Comment: You've tagged the question with JavaScript, I'd assume you've an attempted solution done with JS too ..?

Comment: Why don't you use the x and y position of the `coords` attribute as the `left` and `top` values in CSS for each seat label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you store the data of your coordinates and labels in a variable or JSON file and generate `<area>` and `<span>` (or a different text element) with JavaScript. This way you have a single set of a data which you can use to render your map and labels.

Consider your HTML to be the following, with an added div for the labels. Your CSS should provide the correct `z-index` to the elements so that the map is at the the top, the labels one level lower, and the image at the bottom.

```
<img src="" alt="" usemap="#image-map"/>
<map class="js-seating-map" name="image-map">
<div class="js-seating-labels"></div>
```

In your variable or JSON you could have a format like the example below. You can make this any way you like, for as long as the structure makes sense and the data can be looped over. (The ellipses (...) are to indicate that there is more data and is only for illustration purposes).

```
const seats = [
  {
    coords: [49, 52],
    radius: 10,
    label: 'Seat 1'
  },
  {
    coords: [95, 52]
    radius: 10,
    label: 'Seat 2'
  },
  ...
];
```

Build two functions, one that creates a `<area>` element and one that creates a `<span>` that functions as the label. Both should use a single seat as an argument. And a single seat being the coordinates and labels, etc.

```
const createArea = seat => {
  const area = document.createElement('area');
  area.shape = 'circle';
  area.coords = `${seat.coords.join(', ')}, ${seat.radius}`;
  area.title = seat.label;
  area.alt = seat.label;
  area.target = '_self';
  return area;
};

const createLabel = seat => {
  const label = document.createElement('span');
  label.classList.add('area-label');
  label.style.left = `${seat.coords[0]}px`;
  label.style.top = `${seat.coords[1]}px`;
  label.textContent = seat.label;
  return label;
};
```

Now loop over all the seat data in your variable or JSON and build the elements for each iteration. Append them to the correct container and you'll have build a dynamic structure based solely on the data provided.

```
const seatingMap = document.querySelector('.js-seating-map');
const seatingLabels = document.querySelector('.js-seating-labels');

for (const seat of seats) {
  const area = createArea(seat);
  const label = createLabel(seat);
  seatingMap.append(area);
  seatingLabels.append(label);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you are a Savior